# expressing consequences with "as" + present simple

Tags: phrase-usage

Looking up "as" in an English dictionary,  I once came across this example: "such a bright light as makes your eyes ake". 
Is the simple present correct here? I would actually  expect the infinitive (...."as to make your eyes ake").
In case it is correct, could anyone show me some more examples (either from everyday's life or any book writer)?.
 Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 3):

The spelling *ake* rather than the modern *ache* is a clue:

> The old fellow shall live till he makes his heart [*ake*](https://books.google.de/books?id=H9kkAAAAMAAJ&q=%22ake%22&dq=%22ake%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj19pmMwbnaAhWnhKYKHX3DBesQ6AEIQjAH), I can tell him that for his pains. —*The Spectator*, 1803.

*As + 3rd per sg transitive verb*, once a common construction, is not nearly as frequently used today. It is grammatical, but dying out.

> Add to this, that the near Neighbourhood of those Mountains causes such Reflexion in the Day Time, [*as makes*](https://books.google.de/books?id=RHlYAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA347&dq=%22as+makes+the%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3-YeiwLnaAhXSx6YKHSByA944ChDoAQhTMAg) the Heat excessive … 1734.
>
> Is not this such Love *as makes* your Blood run cold? [*as causes*](https://books.google.de/books?id=RwJgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA33&dq=%22as+makes+your%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibnJmNvrnaAhWIE5oKHfnCCwQQ6AEINDAD) the Ears of him that heareth to tingle? — John Wesley, 1755.
>
> The art of handing Baby round to kiss, during dessert, in a manner so enticing [*as will make*](https://books.google.de/books?id=tRIDAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA253&dq=%22as+makes+your%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibnJmNvrnaAhWIE5oKHfnCCwQQ6AEIKTAB) your richest old friend present anxious to stand godfather. —  *Punch* Magazine, 1872.

There are a few exceptions where one may still find this construction, both with verbs with the no longer productive prefix *be-*: *become* and, as @ChuckkHubbard pointed out, *befit*:

> In the earlier works Berkeley's expository principles are put forward in a dialectical and necessarily blunt fashion *[as becomes](https://books.google.de/books?id=HIIJBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA15&dq=%22as%20becomes%20a%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibzZHf4bnaAhWGjCwKHRoKAFg4KBDoAQgpMAE)* a reformer. 2012.
>
> This is a very large book, [*as befits*](https://books.google.de/books?id=-YFNfV5fRDgC&pg=PA11&dq=%22as%20befits%20a%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqlI3S47naAhWlyKYKHdL1B5oQ6AEIKTAB) a long life and a career that included high achievement and deep failure. 1996.

Use with a linking verb has never gone out of fashion:

> Let us begin — *[as is fitting](https://books.google.de/books?id=ffxNh8WfvvcC&pg=PA241&dq=%22as%20is%20fitting%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3mtX55LnaAhUBBSwKHZr5CG84ChDoAQhaMAk)* — with what is familiar. 1997.
>
> If this is not so, again, punish those responsible *[as seems appropriate](https://books.google.de/books?id=k7HQAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT163&dq=%22as%20seems%20appropriate%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie-Pub5rnaAhVDWiwKHXdYBuMQ6AEIOjAE)*. 2014.

The verb *appear* is more limited in this construction, but still current in official or legal contexts and in making a citation:

> …the court shall make such order as to the postponement of the trial [*as appears necessary*](http://www.irishstatutebook.ie/eli/1924/act/44/section/6/enacted/en/html).
>
> A revised Memphis Conference Budget Summary 2012 Askings ([*as appears*](https://www.memphis-umc.net/newsdetail/45762) on page 18 of the 2011 pre-conference booklet) has been prepared by Conference Treasurer James Finger…

Comment: One phrase where this can still be heard occasionally is with "befits": She was buried in the cathedral, as befits someone of her position." From https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/befit

Comment: @ChuckkHubbard: thanks for pointing that out. I added _befits_, which made me think of _becomes_ and to make a note of linking verbs.